# CakePHP Insert Statements

Tags: cakephp

I am having trouble inserting data into a MySQL table using CakePHP. I am making a table that once a row is inserted, it should not be able to be overwritten. With the save method of CakePHP, if I try to enter something with the same primary key but different information, it will just update that entry instead of returning an error. I tried to unset the id for the model and also tried to do Model->create() before the call, but it still just overwrites the data.

Additionally, I have been trying to use the Model->query() method instead, but I cannot get it to properly check for errors. I want it to insert, but return an error message if the ID is already taken, so I tried this.

```
$insertQuery = ("INSERT INTO `students` VALUES ('{$id}', '{$lastname}', '{$firstname}', '')");
$this->Student->query($insertQuery) or die("error" .mysql_error());
```

However, the query command returns an array and not a truth value, so this will call die every time. I would appreciate any advice someone can give.

Comment: a) what cakephp version b) did you read the docs and tutorials? that is not how anyone would ever do it. try to use the wrapper methods as documented - in your case save().

Answer (score 0):

Your table should have only the Id as the primary key and it should be IDENTITY.

In CakePHP if you dont specify the Id in the form you create to submit your data it will create another record, even with the same values.

But you should revise your model to be sure that the id is not required or something like that.